# selecting all the columns which are present in the table per page at a time

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

This JS file contains the controller which contains the logic of setting up pagination and  logic for single selection and multiple selection of the checkbox.
When I am clicking on select all then it is selecting all the possible records irespective how much records are there in the table at that time.For ex if pagination is showing up 10 records per page and user clicks on select all then user should select only those 10 records insted of all the possible records.

```
angular.module('ControllerModule', [])
    .controller('BundleCtrl',['$scope','BundleService',function($scope, BundleService){
        console.log("Inside Controller 1");

        $scope.ordered_columns = [];
        $scope.allItemsSelected = false;

        $scope.viewby = 10;
        $scope.totalItems = $scope.bundles.length;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.itemsPerPage = $scope.viewby;
        $scope.maxSize = 5; //Number of pager buttons to show

        $scope.setPage = function (pageNo) {
            $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
        };

        $scope.pageChanged = function() {
            console.log('Page changed to: ' + $scope.currentPage);
        };

        $scope.setItemsPerPage = function(num) {
            $scope.itemsPerPage = num;
            $scope.currentPage = 1; //reset to first page
        }

        $scope.selectEntity = function () {
            // If any entity is not checked, then uncheck the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bundles.length(); i++) {
                if (!$scope.bundles[i].isChecked) {
                    $scope.allItemsSelected = false;
                    return;
                }
            }

            //If not the check the "allItemsSelected" checkbox
            alert("after loop");
            $scope.allItemsSelected = true;

        };

        $scope.selectAll = function () {
            // Loop through all the entities and set their isChecked property
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bundles.length; i++) {
                $scope.bundles[i].isChecked = $scope.allItemsSelected;
            }
        };

        }]);
```

HTML

```
<!-- HTML code for the table which has all the columns with the select boxes-->

<div class="row">
  <input id="search" name="q" type="text" size="40" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search (by bundlename, RAG, ID)">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-top:5px">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <label>
            <th>
              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="allItemsSelected" ng-change="selectAll()">Select All
            </th>
          </label>
          <th>{{ all_columns[0]}}&nbsp<span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('RAGStatus')"><img class="img"
                                                                                                                        ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('RAGStatus')"><img class="img" ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>
          <th>{{ all_columns[1]}}&nbsp<span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('Status')"><img class="img"
                                                                                                                         ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('Status')"><img class="img" ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>
          <th>{{ all_columns[2]}}&nbsp<span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('BundleID')"><img
                                                    class="img" ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('BundleID')"><img class="img" ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>
          <th>{{ all_columns[3]}}&nbsp <span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('BundleName')"><img
                                                    class="img" ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('BundleName')"><img class="img" ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>

          <th>{{ all_columns[4]}}&nbsp<span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('ofOrders')"><img
                                            class="img" ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('ofOrders')"><img class="img"
                                                                                          ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>

          <th>{{ all_columns[5]}}&nbsp<span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('ofClosedOrders')"><img
                                                    class="img" ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('ofClosedOrders')"><img class="img"
                                                                                      ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>
          <th>{{ all_columns[6]}}&nbsp <span ng-if="!custom" ng-click="dataSort('Actions')"><img
                                                    class="img" ng-src="resources/images/down-black-arrow.png"> </span>

            <span ng-show="custom" ng-click="dataSort('Actions')"><img class="img" ng-src="resources/images/up-black-arrow.png">
                        </span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="entity in bundles.slice(((currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage),((currentPage)*itemsPerPage)) | filter : search |orderBy:predicate:reverse" ng-class="{selected: bundles.isChecked}">
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="bundles[$index].isChecked" ng-change="selectEntity()">
          </td>
          <td ng-class="entity.RAGStatus"></td>
          <td>{{entity.Status}}</td>
          <td>{{entity.BundleID}}</td>
          <td><a href="#!">{{entity.BundleName}}</a>
          </td>
          <td>{{entity.ofOrders}}</td>
          <td>{{entity.ofClosedOrders}}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="btn btn-default follow following"><span>{{entity.Actions}}</span>
            </div>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <span>View
                            <select name="singleSelect" id="viewPage" ng-model="viewby"
                                    ng-change="setItemsPerPage(viewby)" ng-options="item for item in options1 track by item">
                            </select> records per page.

                            <a href="#module2">
                                <button>New</button>
                            </a>

                            </span>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- the code ends here which was my html code -->
```

image contains the view of my table with all the select boxes
[image: image contains the view of my table with all the select boxes]

Comment: What is the specific problem? Suggest you scale this down to a minimal representation of your issue and create a demo